# Duplicate sites when using getItemSummaries

Tags: yodlee

When using the `getItemSummaries` command (through both the SOAP/REST API) I recently started getting a duplicate entry for the exact same site (or institution). This is using real world data (not DAG bank).

The duplicate entries have one version (verified by looking inside of `itemData` being more recent than the other)

Is there any documentation as to how (and why?) this can happen. According to the docs, `getItemSummaries` is meant to dispaly the latest data of sites

Answer (score 0):

Could you please use [getItemSummariesForSite](http://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/getItemSummariesForSite) (REST/SOAP) and check if you are still getting duplicate accounts? Ideally having duplicate sites(i.e. with same credentials) should not be a use case.

Comment: Just did a `getAllSiteAccounts` to retrieve an array of `SiteAccountInfo`, iterated through the array and ran the `getItemSummariesForSite`, still getting the same results

Just to be more clear, I am getting duplicates of `Sites`, not `ItemSummaries` (i.e. I have 2 exact copies of the same site)

Comment: If you are already a customer then please use Yodlee Customer Care tool for raising a Service Request else you can please fill out the form mentioned [**here**](http://solutions.yodlee.com/APIDeveloperInquiryForm.html) to provide the details like siteAccountId & REST URL you are using for us to debug further.